# How to remove an array from another array in redux state javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following  data :

```
removed_users = [1]
```

And

```
userProfile = [{id:1 , user:{id:1,username:test}} ,
               {id:2 , user:{id:2,username:test2}} ,]
```

What i wish to do:
I wish to be able to remove the correct objects from userProfile , based on the array `removed_users` . I have tried the following code below but its not removing it from the array

```
state.project['userProfile'].filter(function(user) {
                                                    return !action.payload.find(function(removed) {
                                                            return removed === user.user.id
                                                                    })
                                                                })}
```

This is the code for the reducer thats supposed to help me remove the `removed_users` from the state

```
        case 'user_remove': return (updateObject(state, {
        project: {...state.project , ['users']:  state.project['userProfile'].filter(function(user) {
                                                                    return !action.payload.find(function(removed) {
                                                                    return removed === user.user.id
                                                                    })
                                                                })}
    }))
```

This is the script for updateObject helper function:

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
return {
    ...oldObject,
    ...updatedProperties
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that you have a mistake in .filter return. Try to `return action.payload.find` instead of `return !action.payload.find`

Comment: I think you want to modify your state stored in `state.project['userProfile']`, but your reducer is storing result in `state.project['users']`. Could you send also your action creator function? I can only guess now what `action.payload` is?

Comment: code is working fine. the question is what does `action.payload` hold?

Comment: action.payload holds the removed_users i apologize! yes its because of the ! sign

Comment: the ! sign? but you said that you need to remove these entries, so filter will return all the other ones, based on ! sign.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in the filter. Use expression like this:

```
userProfile.filter((user)=>!removed_users.includes(user.id))
```

See full example in the playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s534466

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove user:

```js
const userProfile = [
  {id:1 , user:{id:1,username:"t1"}} ,
               {id:2 , user:{id:2,username:"t2"}}]

const arr= [1];
const filtered = userProfile.filter(({user})=> !arr.includes(user.id)); 
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Dispatch an action for deleting a user by its id.

```js
function removeUser(id){
   return {
     type: "REMOVE_USER",
     payload: id
   }
}
dispatch(removeUser(1))
```

2. Filter users in the reducer that the users id is not equal with received id. And then set new filtered users in the state which not include removed users.

```js
function reducer(state, action){
   switch(action.type){
     case "REMOVE_USER":
        return {
          ...state,
          users: state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload),
        }
     // other cases
   }
}
```

Good luck.